# Generate date ranges in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a document like,

```
    {
       a : "123",
       b : [
             { 
               "start" : "2015-01-03",
               "end"   : "2015-01-05",
               "name"  : "xyz"
             },
             { 
               "start" : "2015-01-15",
               "end"   : "2015-01-17",
               "name"  : "abc"
             }
            ] 
    },
    {
       a : "456",
       b : [
             { 
               "start" : "2015-01-04",
               "end"   : "2015-01-05",
               "name"  : "xyzd"
             }
            ] 
     }
```

I'm trying to get the count of b for each day like,

```
2015-01-03 count: 1
2015-01-04 count: 2
2015-01-05 count: 2
2015-01-15 count: 1
2015-01-16 count: 1
2015-01-17 count: 1
```

This can be done by a simple aggregation if the dates were expanded. Is is it possible to expand the date range for an aggregation?

Edit: basically for a given range I want to expand that range and get the count for each day, which will be one unless it overlaps with another range(s).

Comment: Yes possible using date range also. But, in your documents `date` not in ISODate format or time-stamp in your current documents `date` looks like a `string` so first you should change `date` from `string`  to `ISODate` and used date range aggregation

Comment: Ok, so if I choose to use ISODates, how do I go about expanding a date range and aggregate it?

Comment: In that case first you should `unwind` `b` and then `match` with `date` greater and less than criteria after that use `group`

Comment: well, that works to count dates which are mentioned in the start and end. Like 2015-01-16 is not present anywhere in the document, but its count is given as 1 in the query result.

Comment: Can you post what exactly your code looks like or your aggregation query ?

Comment: Well, I have not written any, as I'm stumped as how to get count for each day for a given date range. I'm not sure this can be done by mongo, maybe I need to get the list and process it in the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75297/discussion-between-yogesh-and-rnet).

Comment: @Rnet did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's check following scenario, If your documents dates like `ISODate` format as given below

```
[
{
    "_id": ObjectId("552e71ec3420d7797e5ae682"),
    "a": "123",
    "b": [
        {
            "start": ISODate("2015-01-03T00:00:00Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2015-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
            "name": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "start": ISODate("2015-01-15T00:00:00Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2015-01-17T00:00:00Z"),
            "name": "abc"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("552e72063420d7797e5ae683"),
    "a": "456",
    "b": [
        {
            "start": ISODate("2015-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2015-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
            "name": "xyzd"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Now If you want count all `start` date then simple use following query

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{
    "$unwind": "$b"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$b.start",
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "startDate": "$_id",
        "count": "$count",
        "_id": 0
    }
}
])
```

**same above used for end date simply replace in group** `$b.start to $b.end` **then it shows end dates count**

Now another problem if you want to find out `start` date count from given range then use below query, suppose `start` date from `ISODate("2015-01-03T00:00:00Z")` and `ISODate("2015-01-04T00:00:00Z")` range

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{
    "$unwind": "$b"
},
{
    "$match": {
   // check here date range matching documents
        "$and": [
            {
                "b.start": {
                    "$gte": ISODate("2015-01-03T00:00:00Z")
                }
            },
            {
                "b.start": {
                    "$lte": ISODate("2015-01-04T00:00:00Z")
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$b.start",
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "startDate": "$_id",
        "count": "$count",
        "_id": 0
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Well, this only works if dates in the documents are expanded. I have just the startDate and endDate in the documents. So, if I just have a single document in which startDate is = 1st, endDate = 30th, then I would need to generate 30 counts, i.e for each date a count

Comment: @Rnet I think simply replace `and` condition with `b.start gt 1st and b.end lt 30th` it will return all matching start date counts

Comment: If you want for all date count of specific documents add also in match. Suppose if you want all counts of `a: "123"` put it in match